# Express cors error in react cannot find property

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

So I'm working in React and keep getting different cors errors. On the internet I found that you can use express to solve the problem!

But now I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

I tried 2 different solutions but it just doesn't work:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.options('*', cors())

export const fetchData = (url, key) => {
    
    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + key);
   
    let requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow',
    };

    return fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => result)
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
}
```

The other one I tried is

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I know . This is a hectic bug for many. For me to overcome this in localhost , I use CORS enable extension available in chrome web store.

Comment: @RitikSingh these extentions are also not working for me ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do both of this:

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

This resolved all my problems with CORS.

Answer (score -1):

use this code to solve cors error

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-Access-Token,XKey,Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  res.setHeader('Expires', 0);
  next();
});
```